# "Total reputation" value change

Tags: support, reputation

A few minutes ago I have noticed a small decrease in my rep (-4), not an issue, just assumed that there were two downvotes. But when I opened my rep for today, I only had:

```
40 today
+10 upvote
+15 accept
+15 accept
```

I then went ahead and calculated total rep as a sum for each day displayed (I have not been here for a long time) and got 4474, while the page displays 4470.

Comparing daily rep shown in profile and rep shown in https://stackoverflow.com/reputation I found these diffs:

```
       profile page | /reputation page
Jun 11          106 | 96     
Jun 22            0 | 10

Jun 30          217 | 215    - no idea what's this (-2)

Jul 2            73 | 58     - accept
Jul 4           223 | 238    - unaccept

Jul 7           227 | 235    - serial downvotes
Jul 8           313 | 307    - undownvote (shown in profile as +8, not +6) (-2)
```

So currently the diff between profile page and /reputation page is "-4", which is exactly the reputation change that I saw today, but cannot find any explanation for this.

Is there some sort of reputation clean-up mechanism that might be the reason for this?

Comment: I think rep can get out of sync from time to time and is periodically recalculated

Comment: @RichardTingle - used to be a common problem. It is very rare these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/reputation` does not include deleted posts **at all**, it's very intentionally the old view as, which is as if deleted things never happened.

I'm strongly considering removing `/reputation` since it seems to only generate bug reports...only 1 of the last 10+ have been a bug.  Even that was only a tally at the bottom, not reputation actually being inaccurate.  We haven't had an actual rep bug in about 6 months - you guys are quick to notice those.